# Is there any other way to get datalayer from Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm trying to get a GTM and datalayer working with following code:

```
{if isset($page_name) && $page_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8' == "index"}
           <script>
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'addToCart',
  'ecommerce': {
    'currencyCode': '{$currency->iso_code|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}',
    'add': {
      'products': [{
        'name': '{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}',
        'id': ' {$product->id|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}',
        'price': '{$product->getPrice(true, $smarty.const.NULL, 2)|round:'2'|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}'
        'quantity': 1
       }]
    }
  }
});
</script>
    {/if}
```

The thing is, that code is working on product page, but not working on index or checkout pages. From all of this i only get "currencyCode" on index, and for everything else - "Undefined index: product in/ Trying to get property of non-object in". 
Perhaps I'm missing something in index/checkout pages script?

Comment: Is $product existing on those other pages, containing the relevant product data?

Comment: @kgrg how can i check it? In controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that's because $product is only available on the product page.

What would you want to get using $product on the index ?
For the checkout you should use something based on the cart. Using directly $product can't give you any results.

Comment: I'm trying to get product name, price and ID on index and category pages for GTM Enhaced Ecommerce

Comment: Do you want to get this informations for the bestsellers/discount/homefeatured tabs ?